# Facing Issue while implementing log4j in my project

Tags: java, maven, log4j

I am facing one strange issue after implementing log4j. So i have created the MAVEN project and added the dependencies of log4j in my POM.XML (as i am using page object model). But whenever I am trying to run my code, after successful execution, the log4j statements are printing multiple times.

log4j dependency in pom.xml --

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->  
<dependency>  
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>  
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>  
    <version>1.2.17</version>
```

Console Output --

```
8685 [main] INFO   - Email ID entered successfully
8685 [main] INFO  - Email ID entered successfully
10786 [main] INFO   - Password entered successfully
10786 [main] INFO  - Password entered successfully
13923 [main] INFO   - Login Button Clicked successfully
13923 [main] INFO  - Login Button Clicked successfully
```

Notes:

- I want to print the logs one time only
- I can't do `Additivity = False` because I am not using log4j.xml, I have just added the dependency in the pom.xml file.

I tried finding so many websites but everywhere its mentioned about log4j xml related solutions, but what if we use pom.xml and add the dependencies.

Comment: Pls add your entire pom.xml

Comment: More importantly, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70123799/edit) your question and add the Log4j configuration. BTW: Log4j 1.2 reached end-of-life 6 years ago. For new projects you should consider Log4j 2.x.